# Как в Simple HTML DOM получить индекс элемента?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Пробую так:

```
$textschet = 0;
foreach($body->find('img') as $e) {
    $textschet++;
}
```

В итоге в переменной `textschet` просто итерация каждого тэга в коде, а как получить индекс именно тэга `img`?

Comment: Как вы определили, что это итерация каждого тэга в коде? Можете привести код `html` который парсите и наглядно показать что не так и что ожидается увидеть?

Comment: Любой код взять, делаю этому же элементу атрибут в виде числа счетчика и он ему назначил число в виде индекса среди всех элементов, да и вывел print_r $e он мне все элементы показывал в переборе, хочу добится чтобы для каждой картинки добавлялся атрибут её индекса

Comment: Боюсь без наглядных примеров, где объясняется все то, о чем вы говорите - никто ничего не поймет и помочь не сможет